# Is there a tool for easily searching hourly rotated logs in S3 from AWS Elastic Beanstalk in aggregated fashion?

Tags: logging, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, aggregation, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It is nice that AWS Elastic Beanstalk can auto rotate your logs for you.  The problem is, once in s3, they are all GZipped and in one file per hour.  In order to do any sort of analyzation over a time period, it requires a manual process of downloading all the individual .gz files, unpacking them, and then searching over them.  I am looking for a tool that I can just point at an S3 folder, and have text search capability over my logs.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in trying to aggregate and search over S3 access and Cloudfront log files. Surprisingly years after this question was posted, I still didn't find a nice solution so wrote my own that uses S3 notifications and AWS Lambda. If you aren't publishing events directly from your app into papertrail and just relying on logs written to S3, you can adapt https://github.com/qixotic/s3-to-logstore to parse your log file format and push into papertrail (or other transport).